# Finding Ranges where condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series

I have a mysql table consisting of a float value from a sensor, and a datetime timestamp of when the reading was taken. the reading are stored at 1 minute intervals(some might be missing).

I am trying to design a query that will give me a list of events (contiguous ranges where the float value is greater than a certain threshold) consisting of the timestamp of the first record in that range that exceeds the threshold, and the end timestamp where the value drops back below the threshold.

```
ID      Value   Timestamp
2172846 1.0 2018-06-29 17:28:00
2172853 1.1 2018-06-29 17:29:00
2172860 1.1 2018-06-29 17:31:00
2172867 1.3 2018-06-29 17:32:00
2172874 1.3 2018-06-29 17:33:00
2172881 1.5 2018-06-29 17:34:00
2172888 1.4 2018-06-29 17:35:00
2172895 1.3 2018-06-29 17:36:00
2172902 1.2 2018-06-29 17:37:00
2172909 1.1 2018-06-29 17:38:00
2172916 1.0 2018-06-29 17:39:00
2172923 1.0 2018-06-29 17:40:00
2172930 1.0 2018-06-29 17:41:00
2172937 1.0 2018-06-29 17:42:00
2172944 1.0 2018-06-29 17:43:00
2172951 1.7 2018-06-29 17:44:00
2172958 2.0 2018-06-29 17:45:00
2172965 1.8 2018-06-29 17:46:00
2172972 1.3 2018-06-29 17:47:00
2172979 1.0 2018-06-29 17:48:00
2172986 1.0 2018-06-29 17:49:00
2172993 1.0 2018-06-29 17:50:00
2173000 1.0 2018-06-29 17:51:00
2173007 1.0 2018-06-29 17:52:00
2173014 1.0 2018-06-29 17:53:00
```

I've done some preliminary research, but I've not gotten much farther.

the expected output from the sample dataset where the threshold is greater than 1 would be something like this.

```
start_timestamp      end_timestamp
2018-06-29 17:29:00  2018-06-29 17:39:00
2018-06-29 17:44:00  2018-06-29 17:48:00
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Im not sure where to start, that is the problem.

Comment: What if there's more than one contiguous range?

Comment: there will be multiple contiguous ranges, i want to find each occurrence.

Comment: Do ID's always go up by 7?

Comment: Can you adjust your sample data set and desired result accordingly?

Comment: @Nick no I just took a subset of the data from one sensor as to not complicate things and omitted the location id from the query.

Comment: @Strawberry data updated

Comment: Is a resultset `<timestamp> <breached/recovered>` acceptable rather than trying to force the start and end of the range to be in the same row in the resultset?

Comment: @gsueagle2008 what's your mysql version did your mysql support window function?

Comment: @D-Shih mysql 8

Answer (score 1):

It is a gaps-and-islands problem, if your mysql support *window function*

you can try this query.

```
SELECT MIN(`Timestamp`)start_timestamp,MAX(`Timestamp`)end_timestamp
FROM (
  select *,MIN(`Timestamp`) over(order by `Timestamp`) mindt,
   ROW_NUMBER() over(order by `Timestamp`) rn
  from T
  where value > 1.0
)t1
group by (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,mindt,`Timestamp`)+1  - rn)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bMFWGt2GFnzHSe5XxLfuBv/1)

Comment: Again, the incrementing minutes are not relevant to this problem

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you would use variables:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(value > 1.0, @grp, @grp + 1)) as grp
      from (select t.* from t order by timestamp) t cross join
           (select @grp := 0) params
     ) t
where value > 1.0
group by grp;
```

Comment: Does it matter that we've put the order by at two different levels?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Yes.  But the more important difference is that you assign `@prev` in one expression and use it in another.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea. It returns a very subtly different range from yours, but perhaps you can figure out how to tweak it...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
,value DECIMAL(3,1)
,dt DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(2846, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:28:00'),
(2853, 1.1, '2018-06-29 17:29:00'),
(2860, 1.1, '2018-06-29 17:31:00'),
(2867, 1.3, '2018-06-29 17:32:00'),
(2874, 1.3, '2018-06-29 17:33:00'),
(2881, 1.5, '2018-06-29 17:34:00'),
(2888, 1.4, '2018-06-29 17:35:00'),
(2895, 1.3, '2018-06-29 17:36:00'),
(2902, 1.2, '2018-06-29 17:37:00'),
(2909, 1.1, '2018-06-29 17:38:00'),
(2916, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:39:00'),
(2923, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:40:00'),
(2930, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:41:00'),
(2937, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:42:00'),
(2944, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:43:00'),
(2951, 1.7, '2018-06-29 17:44:00'),
(2958, 2.0, '2018-06-29 17:45:00'),
(2965, 1.8, '2018-06-29 17:46:00'),
(2972, 1.3, '2018-06-29 17:47:00'),
(2979, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:48:00'),
(2986, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:49:00'),
(2993, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:50:00'),
(3000, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:51:00'),
(3007, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:52:00'),
(3014, 1.0, '2018-06-29 17:53:00');

SELECT MIN(dt) dt_start
     , MAX(dt) dt_end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev=(value<=1) THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=value<=1 prev 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null, @i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) x 
 WHERE prev=0 
 GROUP   
    BY i;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| dt_start            | dt_end              |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-06-29 17:29:00 | 2018-06-29 17:38:00 |
| 2018-06-29 17:44:00 | 2018-06-29 17:47:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```